# Running single junit test in gradle passes but fails when entire test is run

Tags: java, gradle, junit

I have an unusual issue dealing with a particular junit test within gradle.  When I run the test as follows it passes

```
gradlew test --tests com.compsci.ic.xbrl.SchemaRefTest
```

However when I run

```
gradlew test
```

it fails with the following stacktrace

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Undeclared namespace prefix in DOM input: link
    at net.sf.saxon.dom.NodeWrapper.getURI(NodeWrapper.java:531)
    at net.sf.saxon.dom.NodeWrapper.getNameCode(NodeWrapper.java:412)
    at net.sf.saxon.om.Navigator.copy(Navigator.java:523)
    at net.sf.saxon.dom.NodeWrapper.copy(NodeWrapper.java:827)
    at net.sf.saxon.om.Navigator.copy(Navigator.java:516)
    at net.sf.saxon.dom.NodeWrapper.copy(NodeWrapper.java:827)
    at net.sf.saxon.om.StrippedNode.copy(StrippedNode.java:448)
    at net.sf.saxon.instruct.CopyOf.processLeavingTail(CopyOf.java:397)
    at net.sf.saxon.instruct.Template.applyLeavingTail(Template.java:175)
    at net.sf.saxon.instruct.ApplyTemplates.applyTemplates(ApplyTemplates.java:343)
    at net.sf.saxon.Controller.transformDocument(Controller.java:1735)
    at net.sf.saxon.Controller.transform(Controller.java:1559)
    at org.custommonkey.xmlunit.Transform.transformTo(Transform.java:211)
    at org.custommonkey.xmlunit.Transform.getResultDocument(Transform.java:233)
    at org.custommonkey.xmlunit.XMLUnit.stripWhiteSpaceUsingXSLT(XMLUnit.java:514)
    at org.custommonkey.xmlunit.XMLUnit.getWhitespaceStrippedDocument(XMLUnit.java:507)
    at org.custommonkey.xmlunit.Diff.getWhitespaceManipulatedDocument(Diff.java:182)
    at org.custommonkey.xmlunit.Diff.getManipulatedDocument(Diff.java:203)
    at org.custommonkey.xmlunit.Diff.<init>(Diff.java:155)
    at org.custommonkey.xmlunit.Diff.<init>(Diff.java:145)
    at org.custommonkey.xmlunit.Diff.<init>(Diff.java:109)
    at org.custommonkey.xmlunit.Diff.<init>(Diff.java:101)
    at org.custommonkey.xmlunit.Diff.<init>(Diff.java:93)
    at org.custommonkey.xmlunit.XMLAssert.assertXMLEqual(XMLAssert.java:228)
    at org.custommonkey.xmlunit.XMLAssert.assertXMLEqual(XMLAssert.java:179)
    at com.compsci.ic.xbrl.SchemaRefTest.testSerialize(SchemaRefTest.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:114)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor43.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:108)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor42.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:146)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:128)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

This test runs fine in ant so I've checked all dependencies between ant and gradle and they all seem to match.  Any additional suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Here is the source code of the test

```
package com.compsci.ic.xbrl;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;

import org.custommonkey.xmlunit.XMLAssert;
import org.custommonkey.xmlunit.XMLUnit;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import com.compsci.ic.xbrl.xstream.URIConverter;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;

public class SchemaRefTest {
    @Test
    public void testSerialize() throws SAXException, IOException {
        SchemaRef ref = new SchemaRef();

        ref.setHref(URI.create("http://example.com"));

        XStream xstream = new XStream();

        xstream.registerConverter(new URIConverter());
        xstream.processAnnotations(SchemaRef.class);

        XMLUnit.getTestDocumentBuilderFactory().setNamespaceAware(false);       
        XMLUnit.getControlDocumentBuilderFactory().setNamespaceAware(false);

        XMLAssert.assertXMLEqual(
            "<link:schemaRef xlink:type='simple' xlink:href='http://example.com'/>",
            xstream.toXML(ref));
    }
}
```

Comment: And how are we supposed to help without seeing any source of the failing test?

Comment: good point, I'll adjust the code above

Comment: Does your tests modify any file during execution

Comment: honestly I am not sure, I did not write these tests nor do I even know a ton about java, I am simply a dev opts guy who has spent the last 2 months converting our ant/ivy package to gradle, this is the final hang up

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that another test is being dirty and bleeding into this test. Things like System Properties or mutable static variables are likely causes. Those static `XMLUnit` mutator methods have a code smell to me

You could try the following which will give each test a "clean" jvm. Note this will slow things down

```
apply plugin: 'java' 
test {
    forkEvery = 1
}
```

See [Test.setForkEvery(...)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/Test.html#setForkEvery-java.lang.Long-)

This is obviously a hack and it's best to find the offending test and fix it to clean up after itself in @After or @AfterTest. If you can't find the "dirty" test you could always initialize the "polluted" statics in  @Before or @BeforeTest of the failing test

Comment: thank you, I will start there and work my way backwards.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding the following to the test

```
XMLUnit.setIgnoreWhitespace(false);
```

Seems that XMLAssert is outdated and will have to overhaul these tests in the future to get everything current.  For now I am in good shape.

Comment: This is in line with my reasoning. I'm guessing there's another test that calls `XMLUnit.setIgnoreWhitespace(true)`. If that test runs first it pollutes the mutable static state. Mutable statics are evil!

Comment: I will look into it and see if I can find it.  These tests were written by a former employee and are kinda a mess, I have the pleasure of trying to figure out what he was doing.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I does in fact look like a few of the tests have `XMLUnit.setIgnoreWhitespace(true)`.  Funny that in ant it doesn't complain.  Well at least the mystery has been solved and knowing that my solution isn't really a hack is comforting.  Thanks again.

Comment: Possibly ant forks a new/separate jvm per test or runs the tests in a different order? Ideally `XMLUnit` would not mutate static state. If one test needed different flags to another, those flags (booleans etc) would exist in an instance (eg `ConfigurableXMLUnit`) that lives and dies within that test rather than bleeding into other tests.